# What models allow the study of the relation between two sets of variables?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-analysis, modeling, predictive-models, canonical-correlation

Usually when you think of a model you have a single target variable which you associate to explanatory variables to try and find a pattern. In contrast with the idea of having a single target (dependent) variable I would like to study the relation between sets of variables, these sets consist of more than one variable.

A first technique that comes to mind is Canonical Correlation Analysis. Bayesian Networks and other graphical models, I guess, can also be used to analyse such things. Any other methods I should be aware of and what could be their conveniences and drawbacks?

Comment: Do you have a number of variables in the two sets or just two variables? Can you draw a graphical model which shows which variables influence each other, or is this information missing?